# rqt_reconfigure not displaying dynamic parameters

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am adding support of dynamic reconfigure to a node following this tutorial. ( http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode ).
code is same as written in tutorial.

**Problem**: loading dynamic parameter in rqt_reconfigure gui 
**System Configuration** : ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 
**Error** : when selecting dynamic_reconfigure node in rqt_gui

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1384492760.076999]
> reconf loading #1/1 0.0 / 0.0sec
> node=/dynamic_reconfigure_node
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/node_selector_widget.py", line 248, in _selection_changed_slot
> self._selection_selected(index_current,
> rosnode_name_selected)   File
> "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/node_selector_widget.py", line 198, in _selection_selected
> item_widget = item_child.get_dynreconf_widget()
> File
> "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/treenode_qstditem.py",
> line 148, in get_dynreconf_widget
> self._param_name_raw)   File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/dynreconf_client_widget.py",
> line 57, in **init**
> group_desc, node_name)   File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py",
> line 152, in **init**
> self._create_node_widgets(config)   File
> "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py",
> line 198, in _create_node_widgets
> widget = eval(_GROUP_TYPES[group['type']])(self.updater,
> group)   File
> "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py",
> line 247, in **init**
> super(BoxGroup, self).**init**(updater, config)
> TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 4
> arguments (3 given)

Snapshot of rqt_reconfigure GUI
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/uacce.png

**However if i remove grouping of parameter 

angles = gen.add_group("Angles")
and change 

angles.add(.....) to -> gen.add(....) 

Every thing works !!!**

snapshot of rqt_reconfigure
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/ivsir.png

i want to change parameter of many sensors  dynamically for that i need sensor grouping. Searched a lot for solution but not able to find solution.
Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101506/rqt_reconfigure-not-displaying-dynamic-parameters/) by [AbhishekMehta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2140/abhishekmehta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Grouping` is not yet implemented and a ticket is [there](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/162) with which I haven't arranged time to implement. Patch is very much appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0